# TFS build with Visual Studio 2017 - no config transforms

Tags: visual-studio-2017, tfsbuild

I have a TFS build that needs to apply web.config transformations. I have it configured with the following MSBuild parameters:

/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:DeployTarget=Package /p:OutDir=$(build.artifactstagingdirectory) /p:UseWPP_CopyWebApplication=true /p:PipelineDependsOnBuild=false

When running the step with Visual Studio 2015, the build works as expected - I get the transforms applied and packages created.

When running the step with Visual Studio 2017, no transforms are applied and no packages created.

Is there another way to configure the build with VS2017 so that config transforms are applied?

Comment: Are you using the SDK builds when compiling with VS 2017 or using the old style csproj file?

Comment: I'm running a TFS build that uses VS2017. It, in turn, executes a command using "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\msbuild.exe" and passing in the solution path, my parms, etc.

Comment: I get that but did you change your csproj file to the new style MSBuild?

Comment: No, what is the new style? Just a clarification, this is not a .net core project. It's a solution with a couple of web applications and a windows service.

Comment: You can still use SDK style build with .net projects that's why I asked. Looks like you didn't change the build to use something like 
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk"> 

I compare the TransformXml task in the Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll library for each version of MsBuild. There is not a lot different there to suggest that anything drastic would changed. can you share your csproj file please

Comment: I'm not sure that's the issue. I just looked through verbose logs of the builds. The one using MSBuild 15.0 has no mention of Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets so no tasks to transform configs either.

Comment: any chance you can put your project file here

Comment: Did you got any error message in build pipeline. Could you share the related detail error message in the build log ?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description and *Hamid's* comment. This may related to your `.csporj` file.  You could try to build the project directly on the build agent with build service account to narrow down  the issue if related to TFS side.

If build locally also got the same error, try below solution:

1. Open the project file (.csproj) of the project failing to load
2. Search for  `<Import
   Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets"
   />`
3. Change it to  `<Import
   Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets"
   />`
4. Reload the project

That will set the correct version of Visual Studio **dynamically** and properly.

Also take a look at this blog： [Cannot open VS 2015 Web project in VS 2017](https://alastaircrabtree.com/cannot-open-vs-2015-web-project-in-vs-2017/) which be helpful show you how to deal with old 2015 project in VS2017.

Comment: That import wasn't in my proj file to begin with - I don't think it's being added when a brand new project gets created either. Either way, I tried adding this   <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets" /> and it didn't help either. (I had to hardcode lower version as it wasn't finding it dynamically for vs2017)

Comment: @Zaneta What's the result if you **manually build your project** on the build agent ? Did you build successfully or got the same  error ?

Comment: Running the build from command line gives same results - no transforms happen.

Comment: @Zaneta  If so seems the issue is more related to your environment setting not TFS side, could you build successfully use your local VS2017, if you could ,suggest you compare the environment of your local develop machine and build agent machine. If not, then the issue must with your project setting.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I was able to make this work is to either run the build using VS 2015 or using MSBuild and pass /p:VisualStudioVersion="14.0" as a parameter. 
With this, VS 2015 target files need to be on the build server as well.